# Why will my two scenes not work with each other?

Tags: flash

I have been trying to create a game in Flash where if you press a certain combination of numbers and letters, it will bring up an extra menu.  I have been having trouble with this part.  Whenever I test this it will bring up the scenes and rapidly switch between them.  I would love if someone could help with this problem.  The option to go back to the first scene is not yet included.

My code:

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;

public class DocumentMain extends MovieClip {

    public var _konamiCodeHandler:Number = 0;

    public var _bounces:TextField;
    public var _highscore:TextField;
    public var _gravityText:TextField;
    public var _ball:Ball;
    public var _resume:Resume;
    public var _cheatMenu:CheatMenu;

    private var _vx:Number;
    private var _vy:Number;

    public const GRAVITY:Number = 2;
    public const BOUNCE_FACTOR:Number = 0.8;
    public const HIT_FORCE:Number = 20;

    public function DocumentMain():void {
        _vx = 10;
        _vy = 0;

        stop();

        _cheatMenu = new CheatMenu;
        _cheatMenu.visible = false;

        _ball.buttonMode = true;

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
        addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyPressed);
    }

    private function enterFrameHandler(e:Event):void {

        // gravitate ball
        _vy += GRAVITY;

        // move ball
        _ball.x += _vx;
        _ball.y += _vy;

        // check stage boundaries
        checkBoundaryCollision();
    }

    private function mouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
        // hit ball on click
        if (e.target == _ball) {
            hit(e.target.mouseX, e.target.mouseY);
        }
        if (e.target == _cheatMenu) {
            gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 2");
        }

    }

    private function onKeyPressed(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
        if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP && _konamiCodeHandler == 0) {
            _konamiCodeHandler = 1;
        } else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP && _konamiCodeHandler == 1) {
            _konamiCodeHandler = 2;
        } else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN && _konamiCodeHandler == 2) {
            _konamiCodeHandler = 3;
        } else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN && _konamiCodeHandler == 3) {
            _konamiCodeHandler = 4;
        } else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT && _konamiCodeHandler == 4) {
            _konamiCodeHandler = 5;
        } else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT && _konamiCodeHandler == 5) {
            _konamiCodeHandler = 6;
        } else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT && _konamiCodeHandler == 6) {
            _konamiCodeHandler = 7;
        } else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT && _konamiCodeHandler == 7) {
            _konamiCodeHandler = 8;
        } else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.B && _konamiCodeHandler == 8) {
            _konamiCodeHandler = 9;
        } else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.A && _konamiCodeHandler == 9) {
            _cheatMenu.visible = true;
            _cheatMenu.buttonMode = true;
            _konamiCodeHandler = 0;
        } else {
            _konamiCodeHandler = 0;
        }
    }

    private function checkBoundaryCollision():void {
        var left:Number;
        var right:Number;
        var top:Number;
        var bottom:Number;

        left = _ball.x - (_ball.width / 2);
        right = _ball.x + (_ball.width / 2);
        top = _ball.y - (_ball.height / 2);
        bottom = _ball.y + (_ball.height / 2);

        if (left < 0 && _vx < 0) {
            _ball.x = (_ball.width / 2);
            _vx *= -BOUNCE_FACTOR;
        } else if (right > stage.stageWidth && _vx > 0) {
            _ball.x = stage.stageWidth - (_ball.width / 2);
            _vx *= -BOUNCE_FACTOR;
        }

        if (top < 0 && _vy < 0) {
            _ball.y = (_ball.height / 2);
            _vy *= -1;
        } else if (bottom > stage.stageHeight && _vy > 0) {
            _ball.y = stage.stageHeight - (_ball.height / 2);
            _vy *= -BOUNCE_FACTOR;

            if (Number(_bounces.text) > Number(_highscore.text)) {
                _highscore.text = _bounces.text
            }
            _bounces.text = "0";

        }

    }

    private function hit(hitX:Number, hitY:Number):void {
        // increment bounces
        _bounces.text = String(Number(_bounces.text) + 1);

        // adjust vertical velocity of ball
        if (_vy > 0) {
            _vy *= -BOUNCE_FACTOR / 2;
        }
        _vy -= HIT_FORCE;

        // adjust horizontal velocity of ball
        if (_vx * hitX > 0) {
            _vx *= -BOUNCE_FACTOR;
        }
        _vx -= (2 * hitX / _ball.width) * HIT_FORCE;
    }
}
```

}

And this is the error I got:

TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::MovieClip@7fffe980281 to CheatMenu.
    at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
    at flash.display::Sprite()
    at flash.display::MovieClip()
    at DocumentMain()

Answer (score 0):

A couple of obvious problems: `gotoAndStop(0, "Scene 2");` seems wrong since there's no frame 0. Do you mean: `gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 2");`

Also you delare a variable `_cheatMenu` but you never instantiate '_cheatMenu' or add it to the display list. I think that's where your Error#1034 is saying.

You should add  `cheatMenu = new CheatMenu;` in your constructor method, and then initialize it like this: `cheatMenu.visible = false` assuming that you want it invisible at the start.

The rapid switching between frames (Scenes?) sounds like a `stop();` statement is missing somewhere.

That may not take care of all of your problems but it should help you move toward the goal.

Comment: I have added the things you said I should but the same thing still happens.  Where exactly should I put stop();?

Comment: Let's see your code now. Where do you add cheatMenu to the display list?

Comment: I still don't see where you're adding _cheatMenu to the display list. How can you click on anything that's not on the stage? Are you following this?

Comment: I add the object using flash it works for the other object I made.  If I need to do something else then I don't know exactly what it is.

Comment: If you 'add the object using flash' then why are you trying to add it with your code? It doesn't make sense to declare an object in code that you've already put on stage in Flash. You may have to go back to the beginning and learn how Flash works before dealing with more sophisticated compiler errors.